# How to run a line of code after finish looping in IOS Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops

I'm new in Objective C (IOS) development and I'm wondering why my code under my loop is executing even my loop is not yet done in process.

Here's my Code:

```
-(void)update_tbl_selectItem_data{


db = [[DbHandler alloc] init];
    ComputeProductPrice *computeProductPrice = [[ComputeProductPrice alloc]init];
    [computeProductPrice ProductPriceComputation];


 NSLog(@"count: %i", [g_allItemId count]);
for (int i = 0; i < [g_allItemId count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"itemID: %@", [g_allItemId objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSString *l_uomqty = [[DbHandler database] getUomQty:[g_allItemId objectAtIndex:i]];

    [db insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data:g_employeeid ProdId:[g_allItemId objectAtIndex:i] ProdName:[g_allDesc objectAtIndex:i] GenName:[g_allGenName objectAtIndex:i] ComputeType:[g_allType objectAtIndex:i] UOM:[g_allUOM objectAtIndex:i] ListPrice:[g_allPrice objectAtIndex:i] UOMQty:l_uomqty];


}
[db updateDatabaseHasChanges:g_employeeid];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"performSegueSoldToToSelectItem" object:nil];
}
```

This Code under my loop is executing even my loop doesn't finish yet.

```
 [db updateDatabaseHasChanges:g_employeeid];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"performSegueSoldToToSelectItem" object:nil];
```

I want my that line of code will execute after my loop. Please help I'm stuck with this.

**EDIT**

Here is Database Methods:

```
-(void)insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data: (NSString *)empID ProdId: (NSString *)prodId ProdName: (NSString *)prodName  GenName: (NSString *)genName ComputeType: (NSString *)computeType UOM: (NSString *)uom ListPrice: (NSString *)listPrice UOMQty: (NSString *)uomqty{



//    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_selectItem_data (femployeeid,fproductid,fname,fgeneric_name,fcompute_type,fuom,flist_price,fuomqty) values ('%@','%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", empID, prodId, prodName, genName, computeType, uom, listPrice, uomqty];

const char *query = "insert into tbl_selectItem_data (femployeeid,fproductid,fname,fgeneric_name,fcompute_type,fuom,flist_price,fuomqty) values (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
//char *err;
if (sqlite3_open([l_SqliteDb UTF8String], &(_database)) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [empID UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [prodId UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [prodName UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [genName UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [computeType UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [uom UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, [listPrice UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, [uomqty UTF8String], -1, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Insert Successful");
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            sqlite3_close(_database);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }


}

sqlite3_close(_database);

}


-(void)updateDatabaseHasChanges: (NSString *)empId{
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE tbl_employee_has_changes SET has_changes=0 WHERE femployeeid='%@'", empId];
sqlite3_stmt *l_statement;

if (sqlite3_open([l_SqliteDb UTF8String], &(_database)) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &l_statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(l_statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Update Successful");
            sqlite3_finalize(l_statement);
            sqlite3_close(_database);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"updateDatabaseHasChanges error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
            sqlite3_finalize(l_statement);
            sqlite3_close(_database);
        }

    }
}
sqlite3_close(_database);
}
```

Comment: it wont happen.Try to put nslog after for loop and check whether its logged at the end or middle of for loop logs. may be something is calling updateDatabse method when you call insertData method.

Comment: I'm glad to see that my answer (from other question of you) helped you about inserting into the sql... but no one will help you in the future, if you not even answer back :(

Comment: @TonyMkenu let's make my question simple. I have my method(1) that run  a loop inside it then I have another method(2) that will call the method(1) on top and it has a NSlog inside it under the calling of method(1). But my question is I want to run the NSLog after finish the loop(Method1) on top of Method(2)

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to execute a method in main tread after current execution.

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be of the db actions take some time to complete and the code after for loop is executing before it.Better way to use a callback method from `insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data` to perform the remaining tasks ie

```
[db updateDatabaseHasChanges:g_employeeid];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"performSegueSoldToToSelectItem" object:nil];
```

Comment: can you give an example of callback

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

The loop MUST finish before the call below.

However, the methods you are calling might be asynchronous, meaning that they run in the background. If that's the case, they may take a while to finish, and you would need some sort of callback or completion method to tell when the database calls you have made are completed.

In order to know what's going on we'd need more information about the database methods you're calling inside the loop.

Comment: I already add my database method please check the edited question

Comment: Duncan is correct in that the way a for loop works, it is not possible to have the code below run before it finishes. What does your log say?  All of the `NSLog(@"itemID: %@", [g_allItemId objectAtIndex:i]);` should be printed before either of the below commands are executed right

Comment: Can you suggest a solution on this I don't know what to do.